# Deserialized object from Entity Framework request contains badly escaped html entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, entity-framework

I keep getting a string, stored as an nvarchar(max) on mssql 2012, from EF with badly escaped html entities. The string represents a JSON object.

Ex. A single ampersand, `&`, is escaped as `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;`

Ex 2. An escaped ampersand, `&amp;`, is also escaped as `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;`

Ex 3. An apostrophe, `'`, is escaped as `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#39;`

I have no idea what is causing this. The data is stored correctly in the database. I can access it from SSMS and view the unencoded values. If the values were being correctly encoded that would also be fine. I'm using EF 5.

The code is simple:

This line gets the JSON object I want -

```
JsonUnpublished orgUnpubJson = putContext.JsonUnpublished.Where(j => j.OrganizationId == orgId && j.FormTypeId == JSONFORMTYPEID).SingleOrDefault();
```

putContext is an instance that subclasses from DbContext and is auto-generated.

```
namespace StandardOrganizationDataEntities
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class PUTDataEntities : DbContext
    {
        public PUTDataEntities()
            : base("name=PUTDataEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<FieldEditHistory> FieldEditHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FormType> FormType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FTApprovedForm> FTApprovedForm { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FTForm> FTForm { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FTMasterForm> FTMasterForm { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JsonPublished> JsonPublished { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JsonUnpublished> JsonUnpublished { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Organization> Organization { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CountryDivision> CountryDivision { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FTEDoc> FTEDoc { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProgramsAreasServedPublished> ProgramsAreasServedPublished { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished> ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NteeCode> NteeCode { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NteeSubCode> NteeSubCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JsonUnpublished is also auto-generated from the DB.

```
namespace StandardOrganizationDataEntities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class JsonUnpublished
    {
        public JsonUnpublished()
        {
            this.FieldEditHistory = new HashSet<FieldEditHistory>();
            this.ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished = new HashSet<ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished>();
        }

        public int JsonUnpublishedId { get; set; }
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public int FormTypeId { get; set; }
        public string JsonBlob { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FieldEditHistory> FieldEditHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual FormType FormType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished> ProgramsAreasServedUnpublished { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a strange case where the JSON would be converted to XML and, at a later point, the XML would be converted back to JSON. This wasn't happening very often so it was difficult to track down.